# jQuery tabs callback after "show" animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a link to a jQuery UI tab, which needs to show the tab, then scroll it into view. My first instinct was to use the basic `$('selector').tabs('option','active',1)` to show it, then bind a callback to the tabsactivate event to animate the body element's scrollTop to the offset of the tabs container. Should be simple, right? But when I click the link, the page doesn't scroll unless the tab is already active.

After much poking around, I discovered the problem: there's a 150 millisecond fade-in animation on the tab, and tabsactivate fires before the animation has completed. So when I try to grab its offset, it's 0, because the tab hasn't actually been shown yet. I'm pretty sure this is the cause, because if I remove the show/hide animations it works as expected.

So in a nutshell, my question is, **is it possible to bind a callback to the built in tabs "show" animation** so that it won't fire until the animation is finished?

If not, what would be a good workaround?

**Edit:** The problem may not have been what I thought after all... posting code below.

### Code (extremely messy and not very optimized)

```
<script>
$(function() {

$('.select-tab').click(function(e){
    var $target = $('#'+this.href.split("#")[1]),
        tabindex = $target.index('.ui-tabs-panel'),
        $tabParent = $target.parents('.ui-tabs-container');
    $tabParent.tabs('option','active',tabindex);
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".scroll").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $target = $('#'+this.href.split("#")[1]),
        $tabParent = $target.parents('.ui-tabs-container'),
        clickHandler;

    function clickHandler(){
        $('html,body').animate({"scrollTop":$target.offset().top},500,'easeOutCubic');
    }

    if( $this.hasClass('select-tab') && $target.hasClass('ui-tabs-panel') ){
        $this.click(function(e){
            if( $target.index('.ui-tabs-panel') == $tabParent.tabs('option','active') ){
                clickHandler();
            } else{
                $(document).one('tabsactivate',$tabParent,function(e,ui){
                    clickHandler();
                });
            }
        });
    } else{
        $this.click(clickHandler);
    }
});

});
</script>

<a class="select-tab scroll" href="#ProductReviews">
    Read all 36 Reviews
</a>

<div class="ui-tabs-container ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul id="product_tabs" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active">
        <a href="#RelatedProducts">Related Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
        <a href="#ProductReviews">Product Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
        <a href="#OrderWithConfidence">Order With Confidence</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
<div id="RelatedProducts" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
    <!-- Stuff Here -->
</div>
<div id="ProductReviews" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden">
    <!-- Stuff Here -->
</div>
<div id="OrderWithConfidence" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-hidden">
    <!-- Stuff Here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI Tabs have a method that fires called `activate`, and it fires after animations completion.

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QT5Tm/

Comment: Hmm, so it does, according to the docs. I've been trying to use activate, but for some reason it still thinks the top offset of the newly-activated tab is 0. I thought that was because it wasn't shown yet, but maybe there's another reason... have to investigate. Thanks for answering!

Comment: When you call `activate`, are you using the `ui.newPanel` param to access the newly shown panel? Could you post your javascript so that we can have an idea of what you've tried already? Check my fiddle, it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Went ahead and accepted this answer since it told me what I needed to know, that the problem was not actually with the animation. Now I'm thinking it has something to do with having two different event handlers on the same link. But that's a different question entirely. Thanks for taking the time to help!